# unable to perform npm installations in laravel vue project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

I am performing **npm install** for my **laravel vue project**. But npm install is showing following errors:

```
gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
gyp verb find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp verb find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp verb find Python - executing "python" to get executable path
gyp verb find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp verb find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp verb find Python - executing "python2" to get executable path
gyp verb find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Python37\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Python27\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python
gyp verb find Python - executing "py.exe" to get Python executable path
gyp verb find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (D:\Projects\Quadque-Tech-Server\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:302:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (D:\Projects\Quadque-Tech-Server\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\Quadque-Tech-Server\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:200:18)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (D:\Projects\Quadque-Tech-Server\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:266:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:420:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:432:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Projects\\Quadque-Tech-Server\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Projects\Quadque-Tech-Server\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN acorn-import-assertions@1.8.0 requires a peer of acorn@^8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN prosemirror-utils@0.9.6 requires a peer of prosemirror-tables@^0.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN css-loader@1.0.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN file-loader@2.0.0 requires a peer of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@6.0.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@6.0.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tanjib\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-08T15_14_38_129Z-debug.log
```

**Note: I installed something using yarn and after that this happened. I have not used yarn before. I think I messed up something.**
Its always showing python errors. Why ?
I uninstalled and installed node.js freshly. But the error is not going . Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that either you haven't installed Python 3.x on your system, or that Python's installation binary folder isn't in your PATH. Python's installer should be able to add its installation's folder to your PATH environment variable.

If you do have Python installed, and still encounter this error, then do the following steps:

1. Right click on the start menu, go to System
2. Click advanced system settings
3. Click environment variables
4. Select PATH and click on Edit...
5. Click New and add Python's installation binary folder to the list.

Comment: The errors are coming in my laravel vue project when I am installing something using npm. Why python would appear here ?

Comment: node-sass uses node-gyp to build its native components. node-gyp requires Python. So that's why Python appears.

Comment: How to solve this  ?

Comment: The errors are only appearing on that project

Comment: You can probably fix it by following the instructions I posted. Do you have Python installed?

Comment: No. no python installed

Comment: That is the problem. Like I said in this answer post, you need to have Python installed.

Comment: installed python but still error in my laravel project

Comment: Have you restarted your command line session after installing? And is Python on the PATH?